# Java Generic Map<T, T> in a Generic class<T> put throws `incompatible types: T cannot be converted to T` error

Tags: java, generics, hashmap

I have the following class:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private Map<T, T> _map;
    public MyClass(List<T> data) {
        _map = new HashMap<T, T>();
        Prepare(data);
    }
    public <T> void Prepare(List<T> data) {
        for (T i : data) {
            if (!_map.containsKey(i))
                _map.put(i, i);
        }
    }
}
```

It throws compile-time error `incompatible types: T cannot be converted to T` at the `put` line in the code. What do I miss?

Comment: Remove the type variable from the method. It is a completely other variable as the one from the class. And as the answer tells you: It hides it.

Comment: By the way: What purpose does a `Map<T,T>` have? A `Set<T>` seems more appropriate.

Comment: I have tried with `public <T> void MakeSet(List data) {` and ends up the same error.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The purpose of it is for parent-child relationship tracking.

Comment: What parent-child-relationship? You are doing `_map.put(i,i)` ?!?

Comment: It's a DisjointSet class that I am working on. You have better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your Prepare method hides the generic parameter defined for the class. Try this instead:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private final Map<T, T> _map;
    public MyClass(final List<T> data) {
        _map = new HashMap<T, T>();
        Prepare(data);
    }
    public void Prepare(final List<T> data) {
        for (final T i : data) {
            if (!_map.containsKey(i)) {
                _map.put(i, i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```